# Rename multiple column names with specific words

Tags: r, rename, data-manipulation

I have a simple data as below:

```
# dt
NAME  ID  col3   col4   col5
AAA    1   10     20     15
BBB    3   40     20     30
CCC    6   100   200    150
```

I want to rename my columns to:

```
# dt 
NAME  ID  col3_dt   col4_dt   col5_dt
AAA    1      10        20     15
BBB    3      40        20     30
CCC    6      100      200    150
```

Rename `col3`, `col4`, and `col5` to `col3_dt`, `col4_dt`, and `col5_dt`

I know I can change the column names line by line:

```
colnames(dt)[3] <- "col3_dt"
```

However, if I have hundreds of columns, how can I do efficiently?

UPDATE:
There are some good answers, but I just use `col` to represent column. If my column names are inconsistent, like `AIR`, `BUILD`, and `LEASE`. How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `regex`, e.g.

```
ind <- grepl('col\\d+', names(dt))
names(dt)[ind] <- paste0(names(dt)[ind], '_dt')
# or
names(dt) <- sub('^(col\\d+)$', '\\1_dt', names(dt), perl = TRUE)
```

**Edit**

```
# Case 1: Exact matches
ind <- names(dt) %in% c('AIR','BUILD','LEASE')
# Case 2: names are of the form 'AIR2', 'BUILD5', etc. 
pat <- paste(paste0(c('AIR','BUILD','LEASE'), '\\d+'), collapse = '|')
ind <- grepl(pat, names(dt), perl = TRUE)  
# Either way then
names(dt)[ind] <- paste0(names(dt)[ind], '_dt')
```

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you. Last line is what I want. I can also specify columns like: `names(dt)[3:5] <- paste0(names(dt)[3:5], '_dt')`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
sw <- startsWith(names(dt), "col")
names(dt)[sw] <- paste0(names(dt)[sw], "_dt")
dt
#   NAME ID col3_dt col4_dt col5_dt
# 1  AAA  1      10      20      15
# 2  BBB  3      40      20      30
# 3  CCC  6     100     200     150
```

You could also do a one-liner with `ifelse()`.

```
ifelse(startsWith(names(dt), "col"), paste0(names(dt), "_dt"), names(dt))
# [1] "NAME"    "ID"      "col3_dt" "col4_dt" "col5_dt"
```

For the updated question, you can use the `%in%` idiom in place of `sw`, as shown in @nate's answer.

Comment: It's bad practice to change the question after you have received answer(s).  Asking a new question is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rename_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   rename_at(vars(matches("col")), ~ paste0(.x, "_dt"))
#  NAME ID col3_dt col4_dt col5_dt
#1  AAA  1      10      20      15
#2  BBB  3      40      20      30
#3  CCC  6     100     200     150
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(NAME = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), ID = c(1L, 3L, 
 6L), col3 = c(10L, 40L, 100L), col4 = c(20L, 20L, 200L), col5 = c(15L, 
 30L, 150L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```